make Sheet Right To Left Excel With OpenXml
I've been going through the OpenXml documentation, but I'm having trouble finding the information I need. Specifically, I'm looking for how to set the default sheet alignment to start from the left instead of the right. Thank For Helping 
i Want  To Create Excel Files In .net 8 And I Use OpenXml And Works Fine But I Cant Make It RTL
    [HttpPost]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ValidationAndVerificationTaaminExcelFile(ValidationAndVerificationTaaminExcelFileDto request)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileAddress = @"D:\Excel\Output.xlsx";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileAddress))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileAddress);
            }
            using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileAddress, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart1.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart2 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart2.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                Sheets sheets = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2), SheetId = 1, Name = "ویزیت شد" };
                Sheet sheet2 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2), SheetId = 2, Name = "ویزیت موفق" };
                Sheet sheet3 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2), SheetId = 3, Name = "mldhsp65" };
                Sheet sheet4 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 4, Name = "Darman" };
                Sheet sheet5 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 5, Name = "ارسال نشده" };
                Sheet sheet6 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 6, Name = "شبیه سازی شده" };
                Sheet sheet7 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 7, Name = "در دیتابیس هست در سازمان نیست" };

                sheets.Append(sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4, sheet5, sheet6, sheet7);


                string[,] sheet1Content = new string[,] { { "Name", "Age", "Country" }, { "John", "30", "USA" }, { "Alice", "25", "UK" }, { "Bob", "35", "Canada" } };
                AddContentToWorksheet(doc, worksheetPart2, sheet1Content);


                // Add content to sheet2 and sheet3
                string[,] sheet2Content = new string[,] { { "Name", "Age", "Country" }, { "John", "30", "USA" }, { "Alice", "25", "UK" }, { "Bob", "35", "Canada" } };
                AddContentToWorksheet(doc, worksheetPart2, sheet2Content);

                string[,] sheet3Content = new string[,] { { "Name", "Age", "Country" }, { "David", "40", "Australia" }, { "Emma", "28", "Germany" }, { "Jack", "32", "France" } };
                AddContentToWorksheet(doc, worksheetPart2, sheet3Content);

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
            DateTime convertedDate = UtilityMananger.PersianToGeorgian(request.Date);
            var IsExist = await _taaminService.CheckForDuplicateRecordByDate(request.ExcelType, convertedDate);
            if (IsExist)
            {
                return Ok(new ResponseDto<List<TaminResult>> { IsSuccessFull = false, Data = null, Message = ErrorsMessages.SubmitedBefore, Status = "Failed" });
            }
            var result = await _taaminService.ValidateExcelFile(request.Date, request.ExcelType);
            return Ok(new ResponseDto<ValidationAndVerificationExcelResponseDto> { IsSuccessFull = true, Data = result, Message = ErrorsMessages.Success, Status = "Success" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO LOG
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            new ResponseDto<bool>
            {
                IsSuccessFull = false,
                Message = ErrorsMessages.InternalError500,
                Status = "Failed"
            });
        }
    }



  private static void AddContentToWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument doc, WorksheetPart worksheetPart, string[,] content)
  {
      SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

      for (int row = 0; row < content.GetLength(0); row++)
      {
          Row newRow = new Row();
          for (int col = 0; col < content.GetLength(1); col++)
          {
              Cell cell = new Cell();
              cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
              cell.CellValue = new CellValue(content[row, col]);
              newRow.AppendChild(cell);
          }
          sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
      }
  }

enter image description here

To set a worksheet to RTL in OpenXML, you need to modify the SheetView property of the worksheet. The SheetView controls various aspects of the worksheet's display, and setting its RightToLeft attribute to true will change the direction to RTL.
Here's how you can incorporate the RTL setting into your existing method:
private static void AddContentToWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument document, 

WorksheetPart worksheetPart, string[,] content)
{
    // ... Your existing code to add content ...

    // Set the sheet view to RightToLeft
    SheetView sheetView = new SheetView() { RightToLeft = true };
    SheetViews sheetViews = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();

    if (sheetViews == null)
    {
        sheetViews = new SheetViews();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(sheetViews);
    }

    sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}

Use this method after filling each worksheet with data. For example:
// Create the worksheet content as a two-dimensional array
string[,] sheet1Content = { /* Your content array */ };
// ... code to add worksheet part ...
// Now add the content and set the view to RTL
AddContentToWorksheet(spreadsheetDocument, worksheetPart, sheet1Content);

Make sure you call this after adding all content to the sheet, as the Save method will finalize the changes. Each worksheet part you want to be RTL should have this method applied to it.
Remember, it's important to handle cases where SheetViews might already be present. The above code snippet checks for the existence of SheetViews and only creates a new one if necessary.

i test It but I Got error When  i Want Open Excel ouput File

What is the error?

When i open output excel file excel show error message file is incorrect

worksheetPart2.Worksheet.Append(new SheetViews(new SheetView() { WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U, RightToLeft = false })); ditambahkan untuk mengatur perataan default agar dimulai dari kiri. Pastikan untuk menyertakan baris ini setelah membuat
To set the default sheet alignment to start from the left instead of the right, you need to modify the XML markup of the sheet. Specifically, you need to set the default horizontal alignment to "left" instead of "right". You can achieve this by adding the appropriate XML markup when creating the worksheet.
you can modify your code to set the default alignment to start from the left:
enter code here
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
[HttpPost]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task ValidationAndVerificationTaaminExcelFile(ValidationAndVerificationTaaminExcelFileDto request)
{
try
{
string fileAddress = @"D:\Excel\Output.xlsx";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileAddress))
{
System.IO.File.Delete(fileAddress);
}
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileAddress, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart1.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart2 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart2.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        Sheets sheets = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

        Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2), SheetId = 1, Name = "ویزیت شد" };
        Sheet sheet2 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2), SheetId = 2, Name = "ویزیت موفق" };
        Sheet sheet3 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2), SheetId = 3, Name = "mldhsp65" };
        Sheet sheet4 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 4, Name = "Darman" };
        Sheet sheet5 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 5, Name = "ارسال نشده" };
        Sheet sheet6 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 6, Name = "شبیه سازی شده" };
        Sheet sheet7 = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1), SheetId = 7, Name = "در دیتابیس هست در سازمان نیست" };

        sheets.Append(sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4, sheet5, sheet6, sheet7);

        // Set default alignment to start from left
        worksheetPart2.Worksheet.Append(new SheetViews(new SheetView() { WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U, RightToLeft = false }));
        
        string[,] sheet1Content = new string[,] { { "Name", "Age", "Country" }, { "John", "30", "USA" }, { "Alice", "25", "UK" }, { "Bob", "35", "Canada" } };
        AddContentToWorksheet(doc, worksheetPart2, sheet1Content);

        // Add content to sheet2 and sheet3
        string[,] sheet2Content = new string[,] { { "Name", "Age", "Country" }, { "John", "30", "USA" }, { "Alice", "25", "UK" }, { "Bob", "35", "Canada" } };
        AddContentToWorksheet(doc, worksheetPart2, sheet2Content);

        string[,] sheet3Content = new string[,] { { "Name", "Age", "Country" }, { "David", "40", "Australia" }, { "Emma", "28", "Germany" }, { "Jack", "32", "France" } };
        AddContentToWorksheet(doc, worksheetPart2, sheet3Content);

        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    }
    DateTime convertedDate = UtilityMananger.PersianToGeorgian(request.Date);
    var IsExist = await _taaminService.CheckForDuplicateRecordByDate(request.ExcelType, convertedDate);
    if (IsExist)
    {
        return Ok(new ResponseDto<List<TaminResult>> { IsSuccessFull = false, Data = null, Message = ErrorsMessages.SubmitedBefore, Status = "Failed" });
    }
    var result = await _taaminService.ValidateExcelFile(request.Date, request.ExcelType);
    return Ok(new ResponseDto<ValidationAndVerificationExcelResponseDto> { IsSuccessFull = true, Data = result, Message = ErrorsMessages.Success, Status = "Success" });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // TODO LOG
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
    new ResponseDto<bool>
    {
        IsSuccessFull = false,
        Message = ErrorsMessages.InternalError500,
        Status = "Failed"
    });
}

}
private void AddContentToWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument doc, WorksheetPart worksheetPart, string[,] content)
{
SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild();
for (int row = 0; row < content.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    Row newRow = new Row();
    for (int col = 0; col < content.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(content[row, col]);
        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
    }
    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
}

}

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
